# Does "Ob Eam Causam" introduce an indirect question

Tags: classical-latin, conjunctive, gaius-iulius-caesar

I apologize if there's an obvious answer here I'm missing, but I can't figure out why this line from De Bello Gallico 5.33 is subjunctive:
"At Cotta, qui cogitasset haec posse in itinere accidere atque ob eam causam profectionis auctor non ***fuisset***..."

Is fuisset subjunctive in an indirect question, or is this subjunctive in a causal clause describing a motivation of someone other than the speaker/writer?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

The sentence structure is "Cotta, qui cogitasset ... atque ... non fuisset, ... deerat..." The verbs are subjunctive because the relative clause is explaining the cause of the upcoming main verb, deerat. Relative clauses of cause often have an additional word to help identify them (quippe/ut/utpote qui...), but this one does not.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Joan The best way to thank users for their help is to vote up all answers (and other questions and their answers) that you find helpful. You can do that by clicking the little arrow up near the top left of the question or answer. You can also choose one answer as the best one to your own question using the little green check mark. [See our Introductory tour for details](https://latin.stackexchange.com/tour). Welcome to the site! This is an excellent first question!

Answer (score 3):

I believe these are all causal relative clauses. "But Cotta, since he had thought that these things were able to happen on the march and since on account of that reason he had not been a promoter of the departure..." It's the same as *providisset* in the previous sentence.

For the relevant grammar, see Gildersleeve & Lodge § 633 or Allen and Greenough § 535 n. *e*.